# Calculate the distance from the axis beyond which the particles have slid off a rotating disk

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

A collection of small particles is distributed on the top surface of a disc that is rotating at 91 revolutions per second, about an axis, which is vertical. Some of the particles slide off, and some remain in place. Take the coefficients of kinetic and static friction between particles and the disc as 1.1 and 1.5 respectively. Calculate the distance from the axis beyond which the particles have slid off.

I am kind of confused about what the free body diagram would look like. Centripetal force is to the centre. What direction is the normal? Also, what does it mean by "distance from the axis beyond which the particles have slid off"? Where is this distance measured from? Is it the distance from which the particles start to fly off? I am struggling with most of this question.

Comment: Distance from axis is not the distance travelled by particle during its motion. It is simply the distance between the final position of particle and the axis of rotation of disk.

Comment: Isnt this question a bit incomplete as what is the radius of rotating disk and number of particle falling and remaining of disk?

Answer (score 0):

The centrifugal force is given by $mR\Omega^2$. Find the value of $R$ for which this force is greater than the maximum frictional force possible.

Comment: Though, what do I use to calculate the frictional force? Generally, it's the normal. What is it here?

Comment: @sadpwner You have a horizontal disc, on it there is a collection of particles, so you have to use the normal which is equal in magnitude to the weight.